# Angular UI popover-html is thowing a $parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show my custom directive in popover. I have tried ot use popover-html from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

But im getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [<h1>hi<h2>] starting at [<h1>hi<h2>].
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%3C&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=%3Ch1%3Ehi%3Ch2%3E&p4=%3Ch1%3Ehi%3Ch2%3E

Plese check the sample code at

Thanks!

Comment: where's the code that generates that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're passing directly to the tooltip, so using something like

`<div tooltip-html="<h1>hello</h1>"`

While this makes sense to most people, this is not how the library seems to expect you to be using this directive.  There is a related post on the github page which discussed this in length: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3790

Here is a plunker that shows how to use the tooltip-html directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/v4NQXJjNDuyjl4agjtA0?p=preview